# Instrumenting VHDL code

Tags: attributes, vhdl, instrumentation

My simulator (which shall remain nameless) is crashing. I can't find out where. (It just crashes when I single step over a wait statement, so I guess it's jumping somewhere else, but who knows where.)

I have been trying to instrument my code to try to find out where. Ideally, I'd line to report filename and line number. This is easy in System-Verilog:

```
$display(`__FILE__,, `__LINE__);
```

or something like that. I had the idea of doing something similar by replacing the 486 occurrences of `begin` in my code with

```
constant CCCCCC : boolean := true; begin report CCCCCC'instance_name;
```

which broke the four architectures, but that was easily fixed. (Most of the stuff is in functions and procedures.) Unfortunately, using the

```
`instance_name
```

and

```
`path_name
```

attributes inside a subprogram also crashes my simulator. Doh! And

```
`simple_name
```

doesn't provide enough information.

I guess I could write a script to do this, but can anyone think of a smart way to do it in pure VHDL?

Comment: I assume your simulator normally steps through every line it executes. (Which in HDL languages takes you all over the code) It almost looks yours is crashing in the 'even scheduler' where it decides what to do next. That could very well be untraceable unless you start removing code until it works. I assume you are familiar with the phrase "What is the last thing you changed?" :P

Comment: The last thing I changed was the simulator. :-(

Comment: As I expected: your **are** familiar with the phrase "What is the last thing you changed"!

Comment: 'INSTANCE_NAME and 'PATH_NAME won't provide a calling path. If report statements were guaranteed to flush OUTPUT (they're not, implementation/platform dependent, test it) your method might work. There's WRITE and flush before and after every wait statement or calls to subprograms with waits in equivalent or explicit processes. oldfart's call for a [mcve] seems a bit easier. Using a simulator that handles whatever exception actually occurred sounds even easier. Submit a bug report if/when you find it.

Comment: Does binary chopping of your code count as a VHDL-only solution? It's not clever, but can end up being quite fast unless you have an absolute monster of a project. You didn't mention which simulator you are using, but the vendor I'm using has excellent support when it comes to helping with tool bugs.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It's not my code and there is a lot of it. I have been cutting it down, aiming towards an MCVE. This instrumentation was part of that process. (My assumption is that when it hits the wait statement, it is jumping somewhere else. But I don't know where.) I have looked at the output of the instrumentation I already have in an other simulator, but it isn't a great deal of help, because the other simulator executes stuff in a different order (as it is allowed to do). I like the idea of using write and flush, assuming my simulator supports flush.

Comment: The idea is to isolate to a process with writes and flushes following resumption and prior to suspension in wait statements. A concurrent  statement with an equivalent process can be expanded and include the equivalent sequential statement. Processes with sensitivity lists have a write/flush as the the first statements for resumption, a write/llush as the last statements for suspension. You're looking for a resumption without a following suspension. You can also dumb down model specific subprograms if you suspect one. Synthesis target or verification model, language features?

Comment: @user1155120 Yes. Writes and flushes after wait statements is a good idea. I'll try that. (They'll already be there after sensitivity lists due to my already having instrumented the begin statements.) It's simulation code.